# PowerShell PSCmdlet fails to find my assemblies

Tags: c#-4.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-cmdlet

I have written a PowerShell Cmdlet in c# and have a problem. When I run it I get an error saying it cannot find one of the assemblies that the code needs. I used fuslogvw to get a dump of the assemblies it is trying to load and it is looking in the wrong places. The assemblies are all in the bin folder but it is first looking in the PowerShell folder and then in the folder where psd1 file is located. Is there something I can add in the config or elsewhere that can help this look in the correct folder. The required assemblies aren’t in the GAC and putting them there isn’t really an option.

------- edit -----

When I say I run the Cmdlet I mean by setting the command line arguments in the Debug option on the project.

The "Start external program" is set to:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

And the arguments are set to:

```
-noexit -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command "& { import-module .\psModules\MyTestCmdlet }"
```

The psd1 file is in the projects sub-folder called psModules and the assemblies needed by the Cmdlet are in the bin folder. When I debug the Cmdlet in visual studio Powershell looks on the powershell folder and in the root of my projects folder.

I am getting the feeling that this is a problem more to do with the way the project is structured.

Comment: This is very confusing... "When I run it" : run what?  Since a Cmdlet written in C# is a dll, you must mean "When I run a script that calls the cmdlet..."  
Could you provide more detail about "The assemblies are all in the bin folder..."  Does one C# dll depend on another C# dll?  Did you use Import-Module for your cmdlet dll?

Comment: Added more detail on what I meant by "running" the Cmdlet.

Comment: In the PS console: If you cd to the psModules dir and run "Import-Module MyTestCmdlet", what errors do you get?
In MyTestCmdlet.psd1, how are you trying to load the C# assemblies (dlls)?

Comment: The cause of this problem was due to my solution having a dll in the wrong place. PowerShell was finding it and then using this position as the starting point to look for the other files. Once I deleted this file the correct one was found and everything worked as expected. @Number8 Thanks for you help.